# Most updated and deleted table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

How can we see most deleted and most updated table in sql server 2012 and upper levels.

And how can we see table that makes the most io?

Does these statistics withheld in Sql Server?

Comment: To a first approximation, this data is contained in [`sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-index-usage-stats-transact-sql). This is only valid since the last startup, though.

Comment: i have written this : select OBJECT_NAME(sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats.object_id) as tablo, sys.indexes.name,
 user_seeks,user_scans, user_lookups,user_updates 
 from sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats inner join sys.indexes on sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats.object_id=sys.indexes.object_id and sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats.index_id=sys.indexes.index_id
 where OBJECT_NAME(sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats.object_id) is not null and DB_ID('MY_DB')=database_id
 order by tablo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Index fragmentation should help - looking at number of rows and fragmentation:

```
SELECT
     B.name AS TableName
    ,C.name AS IndexName
    ,C.fill_factor AS IndexFillFactor
    ,D.rows AS RowsCount
    ,A.avg_fragmentation_in_percent
    ,A.page_count
FROM 
    sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(),NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL) A
INNER JOIN 
    sys.objects B
ON 
    A.object_id = B.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.indexes C
ON 
    B.object_id = C.object_id AND A.index_id = C.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions D
ON 
    B.object_id = D.object_id AND A.index_id = D.index_id
WHERE 
    C.index_id > 0
order by
    avg_fragmentation_in_percent desc
```

PFE: Thanks to Neeraj Dwivedi at SQL Central